# Phonegap - How to copy selected file from galley to folder in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova

I have three options in my application

1. **Photo** : Here you can capture photo through Camera.
2. **Video** : Here you can capture video through Camera.
3. **Upload from Gallery** : Here you can select any file (photo or video ) from library.

Using these three options I want to copy each selected file to particular folder.
So Till now I am able to copy capture images to newly created folder through first option.

and in option 2, I am not able copy video file as it throws error code 1.

and I am not able copy files which is selected through library i.e option 3 in my list.

So I need help to resolve option 2 and 3.

Please get me out of this issue. Tell me how to copy file, selected through library to specific folder.

Please let me know if need more info.

**Update**

Code for option 3

```
accessPhotoLibrary = function(source) {
    //  alert(source);
    //alert('Inside PhotoLibrary');
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
        sourceType: source,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
    });
};

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageData) {
    // Get image handle
    moveFile(imageData);

}

  function moveFile(file) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError);
 }

 function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    //new file name
    var newFileName = "mobile" + n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "mobile";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
        //The folder is created if doesn't exist
        fileSys.root.getDirectory(myFolderApp,
                {create: true, exclusive: false},
        function(directory) {
            entry.copyTo(directory, newFileName, successMove, resOnError);
        },
                resOnError);
    },
            resOnError);
}
```

Comment: `Please let me know if need more info.` yes, please provide code related to your issue so we can help debug the root of the issue. Also listing things like 1) local build or build.phonegap.com 2)phonegap/cordova version 3) all plugins used

Comment: I am using Local Build and Phonegap version 3.5.0